# How to view container logs in GKE's Logs Explorer

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

In my GKE cluster (version v1.21.10-gke.2000) I would like to see output produced by pods/containers as logs in Logs Explorer.

But clicking on Container Logs link in Workloads' Overview tab makes Logs Explorer return 'No data found'. Cloud Logging is enabled (Components: System, Workloads). Cloud Logging API is enabled as well.

What I have tried so far:
In another (test) project in a freshly created cluster (version 1.22.8-gke.201) this works correctly, i.e. what `kubectl logs` returns is also visible in Logs Explorer. The cluster mentioned at the beginning was created long ago and apparently requires some changes - how can I figure out what cluster (or maybe node pool) settings need to be modified to be able to see container logs in Logs Explorer? I would like to avoid creating a new cluster from scratch.

Comment: If kubectl logs is producing something then you know there are logs. A service account is responsible to send logs to Cloud logging. Check whether your SA has proper permissions. MENU> COMPUTE ENGINE> check 1 VM.[to check SA]. Menu >  IAM [to check permissions]

Comment: Default SA should have editor and should work. If you are using your own SA, do a test with logging admin

Comment: In both cases I'm using default SA described as 'Compute Engine default service account' which has assigned Editor role and this is the only role assigned. So why in one case does it work and in the other does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't see any of your logs in Cloud Logging, you could try the instructions here in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/finding-your-gke-logs) about `How to find—and use—your GKE logs with Cloud Logging` and find the `Make sure you’re collecting GKE logs` section.

Comment: Thanks for the link to this blog post. In the section you mentioned there was a link to documentation about [logging exclusions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions) which helped me to pinpoint the root cause of my problem - I had an exclusion filter like `resource.type=("container" OR "k8s_container")` effectively preventing all container logs from being ingested by Cloud Logging.